# Dynamically add choices in MultipleChoiceField in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and working on creating an app where I need to display a checkbox for users email. The problem is, the tuple is populated when the server is started, but new users emails do not show up directly and I need to restart the server. How do I go about doing this?
This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User


class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')


class Login(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

Comment: can you paste the whole code ??

Comment: By users, do you mean the choices have to be populated from a database table?

Comment: You want to show up emails in dropdown? why checkbox it is either `on` or `off`

Comment: @AswinMurugesh yes. I need to get the users emails.

Comment: So in the form you want the user to select multiple emails.. correct?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari No, not a dropdown, I need a checkbox so I can select multiple emails at a time.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) . Eg:

```
class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):

    emails = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Whats the difference between the solution mentioned by you and the one mentioned by Yugandhar Chaudhari ? And also, just out of curiosity, what should I do if I want a checkbox instead of this list ?

Comment: @Vai The solution mentioned by Yudandhar adds the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget to the field, which gives you the checkbox UI you wanted. And in his code, the queryset is configured dynamically, which is useful when you want to list users that only pass a certain conditions. E.g (List only active users)

Answer (score 1):

You need `MultipleChoiceField` and `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget you can populate at the time form initialization in `__init__` like this:

```
class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):
    email = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = [], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['email'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[ o.email for o in User.objects.all()]) #your query here
```